# wget or lynx not able to download some webpages due to frames contained in it

Tags: unix, download, frame, wget, lynx

I want to download http://www.wordwebonline.com/search.pl?w=humane  this webpage on UNIX.

I tried to use wget and lynx but the page is not download. Instead following text is seen in it

FRAME: [2]fr_top
   FRAME: [3]fr_bottom

Your browser doesn't support frames: Click on the link below to
   proceed to the

With wget -U Mozilla option was also tried but still the same result
So how can I overcome this? How to get the data within frames using either wget or lynx. Or any other command line tool  to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a SO question but check out [HTTrack](http://www.httrack.com/)